# Restriction of scalars for representations of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $K$ be a finite field.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional absolutely irreducible $K[G]$-module. For any subfield $F \subseteq K$, we can consider $V$ as a $F[G]$-module (of dimension $[K:F] \dim V$).

A basic (vague) question: What does $V$ look like as an $F[G]$-module? For example, when is it irreducible? What is the endomorphism ring?

This is all probably well known, but I would like know if there is a textbook reference for these kind of questions.

Some thoughts: Let $W$ be an irreducible $F[G]$-submodule of $V$. Since $V$ is an irreducible $K[G]$-module, it follows that $W$ spans $V$ as a $K$-vector space. Thus if we take an $F$-vector space basis $\alpha_1$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_t \in K$ of $K$ (here $t = [K:F]$), we have $$V = \alpha_1 W + \cdots + \alpha_t W.$$

Each $\alpha_iW$ is an irreducible $F[G]$-module and isomorphic to $W$, so as a $F[G]$-module $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of some number of copies of $W$. (What is this number?) At this point a reasonable guess might be that $End_{F[G]}(W) = K$ and $End_{F[G]}(V)$ is a matrix algebra over $K$.

Comment: I will write this as a comment, because I am not sufficiently sure that it is correct, and it does not completely answer the question anyway, but I think what happens is as follows. Let $L$ be the smallest subfield over which $V$ can be written - in fact $L$ is the subfield spanned by the traces of the elements of $G$. Then expanding to an $L[G]$-module in the way you describe will result in it splitting into $|K:L|$ irreducibles, all isomorphic to the original. But these will remain irreducible on expanding to $K[G]$-modules for subfields $K$ of $L$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks. The first part seems clear, if the representation can be written over $L$ then $V = W \otimes_L K$ for some irreducible $L[G]$-module $W$, and so as an $L[G]$-module $V$ is a direct sum of $[K:L]$ copies of $W$. Not sure how to see that if $F$ is a subfield of $L$, then $W$ is irreducible as an $F[G]$-module.

Comment: Actually it seems it follows from Isaacs 9.21 that in this case $W \otimes_F L$ will be irreducible and multiplicity-free. Thus $End_{L[G]}(W \otimes_F L) \cong End_{F[G]}(W) \otimes_F L$ should be a commutative ring, hence $End_{F[G]}(W)$ is a commutative ring, hence $W$ is irreducible.